# If I curl a raw script and pipe that output into a bash interpreter, how do I preserve an environment variable that was set in that retrieved script?

Tags: bash, curl, environment-variables

So I'm using a conjunction of npm's scripts (defined in `package.json`) and regular bash scripting.

In the overarching script, there is a point in execution where I write `npm run set-my-env` where the variable `FOO` is set:

```
npm run set-my-env
... do stuff with $FOO
```

I'd like to make a variable accessable in a way that calling the BASH interpreter doesn't tell me it's undefined. The issue being that $FOO isn't defined when I return to the script. I get that this is how processes work and whatnot, but this can't be a novel problem right?

`set-my-env` actually `curl`s a GitHub endpoint that pipes the raw input into the bash interpreter. Not sure if this makes the overall issue any more convoluted but thought I should mention it.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: It is not possible to set an environment variable in a parent process from the child. You could do something like write the value to a buffer (such as a file) that will persist after the process finishes, and source it in the parent. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for more information.

Comment: It's worth looking at how other programs that need to change environment variables, like `ssh-agent`, do it: They write correctly-quoted shell script text to stdout, and rely on the parent shell to `eval` it. Thus, use of ssh-agent is `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`, where `-s` specifies that output should be for a POSIX-y shell (with other options for output for different shells, like csh).